# An adjective for the word "reference"?

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

What is an adjective for the word "*reference*"? I want to write something as:

> For your *reference convenience*, I have attached the following
>   documents.

However, clearly, "*reference*" is not an adjective for this sentence to be syntactically right.

What would be an adjective to the word "*reference*" to tell the idea that an action was done so that the recipient can *refer* to something *conveniently*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The adjective from *reference* is *referential*, but it wouldn't be appropriate here. I'd have thought 'for your convenience' would have been enough, but another formulation sometimes used is 'for ease of reference'.

Comment: I agree with Barrie; 'for your convenience' seems sufficient. If you really wanted to include _reference_, you could move it: _For your convenience, I have attached the following reference documents._

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, Barrie and JR! Really helpful. :)